# Kangaroo method on pattern matching with atmost K mismatches allowed

Tags: design-patterns, matching

I searched everywhere but didn't find a good, clear explanation on Kangaroo method. Only that I found was some ppts but were useless to me as I have not read kangaroo method before.Those ppts were for revision of the kangaroo method.

Please if anybody can provide me a reading material on kangaroo method or a video tutorial link, it will be a great help.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 4):

**Let T=t1t2...tn, P=p1p2...pm**

**k=# errors permitted**

Preprocess a suffix tree for T$1P$2 [Time: O(nlog|Sigma| by Weiner algorithm to construct a suffix tree) Sigma is the language.

Preprocess an LCA on the tree we just created. [Time: O(n)]

Run on all nodes and write on each node it's height from the root. [Time: we have O(n) nodes]

Iterate over all the suffixes(=leaves) and for each suffix Si initialize an err counter and query the h1=height(LCA(Si,P)), if h>=m we add i to the solution, else: err++ and if err<=k continue to check h2=height(LCA(Si[h1+1,n],P[h1+1,m])).

[Time: running over all suffixes => O(n), for each suffix running up to k+1 times => O(kn)]

Hope this is helping...

Bush